# What is the difference between an AutoProperty and Member

Tags: c#, mvvm, mugenmvvmtoolkit

In [MugenMvvmToolkit](https://github.com/MugenMvvmToolkit/MugenMvvmToolkit), What is the difference when using `CreateAutoProperty` vs using `CreateMember`.  What is an example of when you'd use `CreateAutoProperty` vs `CreateMember`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateAutoProperty` is analog of auto property from C#, it creates get, set and observe members, you can listen when this property is changed.

`CreateMember` you can control logic of set, get and observe methods you are responsible where you will store the state of this member.

```
public class AttachedPropertySample
{
    private string _autoProperty;
​
    //this is equivalent to AttachedBindingMember.CreateAutoProperty<AttachedPropertySample, string>("AutoProperty", OnAutoPropetyChanged);
    //In auto member you cannot control logic of set and get method you can also listen when this property is changed
    public string AutoProperty
    {
        get { return _autoProperty; }
        set
        {
            _autoProperty = value;
            OnAutoPropetyChanged();
        }
    }

    //this is equivalent to ​AttachedBindingMember.CreateMember<AttachedPropertySample, string>("CustomMember", (info, sample) => "My custom value", (info, sample, arg3) => CustomMemberSetter(arg3))
    //In custom member you can control logic of set, get and observe methods
    public string CustomMember
    {
        get { return "My custom value"; }
        set { CustomMemberSetter(value); }
    }

    private void CustomMemberSetter(string value)
    {

    }
​
    private void OnAutoPropetyChanged()
    {
    }
}
```

You can use `CreateAutoProperty` when you need to store some value and react when this value is changed.

Here's an example when I used `CreateAutoProperty`:

```
AttachedBindingMember.CreateAutoProperty<ActionBar, bool>("DisplayShowHomeEnabled", (actionBar, args) => actionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(args.NewValue));
```

`ActionBar` doesn't have the `DisplayShowHomeEnabled` property and I added it using `CreateAutoProperty`.

Here's an example when I used `CreateMember`:

```
AttachedBindingMember.CreateMember<IMenuItem, bool>(nameof(IMenuItem.IsVisible), (info, item) => item.IsVisible, (info, item, value) => item.SetVisible(value));
```

`IMenuItem` already has the `IsVisible` getter and the `SetVisible` method I combined them using the `CreateMember`.